# How can I get TypeScript to build iterables in ES6 to ES5?

Tags: javascript, typescript, set, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a unique array of user objects in Angular 2 writing in TypeScript.  I was using the short and elegant ES6 way to create a unique Array:

```
  this.users = Array.from(new Set(this.users))
```

I get this error when I build the TypeScript to ES5:

> Argument of type 'Set<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IterableShim<{}>'.
>     Property '"*es6-shim iterator*"' is missing in type 'Set<{}>'.

I tried setting `this.users : IterableShim<T>` but IterableShim is not an acceptable type like string. The docs say String, Array, TypedArray, Map and Set are all built-in iterables, because the prototype objects of them all have a Symbol.iterator method. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators )  Is there a way to get TypeScript to compile ES6 that it recognizes as iterables to ES5 without errors?

Comment: ES5 doesn't have Sets or Array.from, or even iterables like that?

Comment: No, they are new in ES6. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: Here's an idea `this.users = this.users.slice()`

Comment: Using slice in no way addresses how to get TypeScript to build iterables in ES5.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `lib` option as:

```
"lib": [
  "dom","es6"
]
```

The following works fine :

```
let users = []
users = Array.from(new Set(users))
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option